# <a> link outside doesn't wrap element when it's another link inside

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a `<a>` link outside of `<div>` to wrap the whole element and gave it `display: block` property, but when I make inside the `<div>` another `<a>` link wrapping just some text inside the `<div>` the outer link becomes `height: 0`.

Is it able to combine one link inside the other?

I made jsfiddle sample to show what I want to achieve, so without the inner link the whole red rectangle is wrapped as a link, but when I add inner link, there remains no link wrapping rectangle.

JSFiddle sample - http://jsfiddle.net/ynbc2d6f/2/

Comment: _"Is it able to combine one link inside the other?"_ No, you can't nest links.

Comment: A link in a link is INVALID Html. Hence why it does not work. What are you actually trying to do with a link in a link?

Comment: Try some logic: how you click on inner link, if it's wrapped with another link, how you click outer link if it contains another link. It's not Inception...

Comment: [w3.org: The interactive element `a` must not appear as a descendant of the `a` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html#a-constraints)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't nest links. What happens is that the browser then compensates for the invalid HTML by closing elements to make it valid, so your original:

```
<a class = "big-link" href = "http://www.google.com">    
    <div class = "big">
        <a class = "small-link" href = "http://www.facebook.com">One</a>
    </div>
</a>
```

Becomes:

```
<a class="big-link" href="http://www.google.com"></a>
<div class="big">
    <a class="big-link" href="http://www.google.com"></a>
    <a class="small-link" href="http://www.facebook.com">One</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a clickable element within a clickable element. See:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-0

Answer (score 0):

According to the [**W3C spec on HTML Links**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2)

> Links and anchors defined by the A element must not be nested; an A element must not contain any other A elements.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: change the outer link to a div block and add the click event listener to it.

```js
$('.big-link').on('click', function() {
  location.href = $(this).data('href')
});
```

```css
.big-link {
  display: block;
  line-height: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.big {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="big-link" data-href="http://www.google.com">
  <div class="big">
    <a class="small-link" href="http://www.facebook.com">One</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Vanilla JS version

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('big-link').item(0).addEventListener('click', function(el) {
  location.href = el.dataset.href;
});
```

```css
.big-link {
  display: block;
  line-height: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.big {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="big-link" data-href="http://www.google.com">
  <div class="big">
    <a class="small-link" href="http://www.facebook.com">One</a>
  </div>
</div>
```